# @FormParam returning null value

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I am working with REST in Java and am having issues using @FormParam.

Right now I have an interface with function:

```
@POST
@Path("/naming/{name}/{age}")
public String populatePerson(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("age") String age, @FormParam("hobby") String hobby) throws Exception;
```

and the implementation is

```
@Override
public String populatePerson(String name, String age, String hobby) throws JMSException {

    return "Made person " + name + " with age: " + age + " and hobby" + hobby;  
}
```

I have created a textarea form for which the hobby will be read from

```
<form action="javascript:submitInfo();">
<textarea id="hobby" name="hobby" placeholder="Enter hobby Here" style="height:300px; width:500px"></textarea>
        <button id="submitButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my submitInfo() function is

```
<script>
        function submitInfo() {

                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var data = new FormData();
                var hobbyValue = hobby.value;
                data.append("hobby", hobbyValue);
                xmlHttp.open("POST", "rest/processor/naming/" + name + "/" + age, false);
                xmlHttp.send(data);
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
    </script>
```

For some reason when I get the response back, it doesn't recognize the hobby value that I enter in the form. It DOES return the proper name and age as @PathParam. Hobby is coming back as null.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing a http header.
try to add application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, after I added that I am still seeing null returned. :(